# Alternate panel.background fill with white and grey

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line plot in ggplot2 that the panel background colors alternate between white and grey based on the X axis values.

In this case `DOY` is day of year and I would like for it to transition between each day.

I included some basic sample code. Basically want between `DOY 1-2` to be white and `DOY 2-3` to be grey and so forth.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
DOY <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Max <- c(200, 225, 250, 275, 300)
sample <- data.frame(DOY, Max)

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=sample, aes(x=DOY, y=Max), color = "black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is to add a new variable (called *e.g.* `stripe`) to the data, which alternates based on the value of DOY. Then you can use that variable as the basis for filled, transparent rectangles.

I'm assuming that `DOY` is a sequence of integers with interval = 1, so we can assign on the basis of whether DOY is odd or even.

(Note: `sample` - not a great variable name as there's a function of that name).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sample %>% 
  mutate(stripe = factor(ifelse(DOY %% 2 == 0, 1, 0))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(DOY, Max)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmax = DOY + 1, 
                xmin = DOY, 
                ymin = min(Max), 
                ymax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey50")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks you answered my question! and yes I realized after using names similar to built in functions is a not good!